# Open link in new page

Tags: search

Where do i put `_blank` in this search script?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#txtSearch').autocomplete({
        source: "post_search.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            var url = ui.item.id;
            if (url != '#') {
                location.href = url
            }
        },
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000)
        }
    })

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `location.href` you can try to use `window.open`. Your code should look like this:

```
window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Comment: There is a check mark just below the arrows to vote this answer up or down - clicking that would make this answer correct.